# Force NSTextField to Only Accept Decimal (#.#) Numbers and Periods

Tags: swift3, nstextfield, nscharacterset

I'm trying to make it so an `NSTextField` will only accept numbers and periods like `12.4` and `3.6` in a Mac app.

I feel like I'm getting pretty close after reviewing other SO questions, but I can't quite get it. The below code works except that it won't allow `.` characters. It returns `true` and doesn't beep at me when I type a `.` **but it won't let the character appear in the field**.

```
class decimalFormatter: NumberFormatter {

  override func isPartialStringValid(_ partialString: String, newEditingString newString: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {

    //Allows the text to be deleted
    if partialString.isEmpty {
      return true
    }

    //Check for #.# numbers
    let charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890.").inverted

    if partialString.rangeOfCharacter(from: charSet) != nil{
      NSBeep()
      return false
    }else{
      return true
    }

  }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39458375/2303865

Answer (score 2):

I found a simpler way to do it. Inside `controlTextDidChange` I just did this:

```
let charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890.").inverted
let chars = fieldDuration.stringValue.components(separatedBy: charSet)
fieldDuration.stringValue = chars.joined()
```

It works great!

Comment: @Clifton Labrum - this is the sweetest answer, EXCELLENT work. This issue is so ridiculous!

Answer (score 2):

@Clifton Labrum solution is really great but it doesn't reduce the field to **Decimal (#.#)**, you can stil put some inputs as `1.2.4` which would lead to an error when trying tu cast it to `Float`.

Here is a draft of an extension that worked fine for me ( **In Swift 4** )

```
public override func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
    if let textfield = obj.object as? NSTextField,
        textfield == self.quantityTextField {

        var stringValue = textfield.stringValue

        // First step : Only '1234567890.' - @Clifton Labrum solution
        let charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890.").inverted
        let chars = stringValue.components(separatedBy: charSet)
        stringValue = chars.joined()

        // Second step : only one '.'
        let comma = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: ".")
        let chuncks = stringValue.components(separatedBy: comma as CharacterSet)
        switch chuncks.count {
        case 0:
            stringValue = ""
        case 1:
            stringValue = "\(chuncks[0])"
        default:
            stringValue = "\(chuncks[0]).\(chuncks[1])"
        }

        // replace string
        textfield.stringValue = stringValue

    }
}
```

This prevent multiple occurences of `.` , even if I know that's not the best algorithmic way to do this. For instance `1.2.4` becomes `1.2` when pasted, and by keyboard you can't add another `.`